# Discover SharePoint 2013 webservices

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I'm struggling to access to some data hosted on a website.

I know this website was developed using Sharepoint 2013 (by someone else, and I don't have any contact with them).

I have the right credentials to the site, and via browser I can navigate and obtain the data I need (some electric measurements).
I need a way to obtain the data using a webservice.
Is there a way to discover all the webservices implemented on the site? And to gain access to those data?
I browsed the lists on _api/Web/Lists but due to my lack of knowledge I didn't find anything useful.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to start you discovery of default SharePoint web services is from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380.aspx)

There are at least 3 default services that you could use to get more information from different lists and webs:

- /_api/site
- /_api/web
- /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items

Unfortunately I don't think there is a way to discover all web services there are on your particular site